# Why does iterating through this char array increment byte in array instead of array value?

Tags: c, arrays, character

I'm new to c, and having a hard time with memory management.

I have a program that takes an array of files, goes through each file, and copies the array into a value in a struct.

When given a list of files `file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt`

The first iteration through my for loop works as expected.  The value taken is as expected `file1.txt`.  On the second loop, the value taken into my `GetFileContent()` method is `ile1.txt` (it cut off just the first bit of the first item in the array).  If I change the i value to 2, it cuts off the first 2 letters to `le1.txt`.

```
char *GetFileContent(char *filePath)
{
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen(filePath, "r");

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);

    rewind(file);

    buffer = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*buffer));

    fread(buffer, size, 1, file);

    fclose(file);

    buffer[size] = '\0';

    return buffer;

}



int main (void)
{   

    char *file = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"};
    int numberOfFiles = sizeof(file);

    struct ArrayStoredInHeap myStruct[numberOfFiles];

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
    {
        struct ArrayStoredInHeap tmpStruct;

        tmpStruct.entireFile = GetFileContent(&file[i]);

        myStruct[i] = tmpStruct;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", myStruct[i].entireFile);
        getchar();
    }
}
```

I expected the value in the second time through the loop to be `file2.txt` as in, the second value in the array, instead of removing 1 character from the array.  I'm assuming the memory I'm referencing is moving by one byte, but I'm not sure how that would be happening in this.

Comment: First thing I would add `fclose` in your function... Second, your `file` type is incorrect. It should be `char *file[]`. Enable all warnings and fix them.

Comment: How did you get this to compile? I got an error in this line: char* file = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"}; I think you want to initialise an array of pointers: char* file[3] = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"};

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the ```fclose()```.  And adding the brackets showed more warnings.  I'll fix those, thanks.

Comment: It compiles with only one warning in its current state (the one warning appeared after I added the brackets suggested by Eugene.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneSh. after adding the brackets, it gave a correct warning that I had a misplaced ```&```.  It's going to take me a while to get used to c.

Comment: If you'll put that as the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: If you're using gcc you should pass the `-Werror` flag so warnings get treated as errors (and `-Wall`, and optionally `-Wextra` to get more warnings). Don't ignore warnings!

Comment: `sizeof(file)` gives the size of the pointer, not what it is pointing to. And anyway, `sizeof` gives the size in bytes not in number of elements.

Comment: A common trick for the number of array elements is `sizeof file / sizeof *file`. This will be computed by the compiler (maintenance friendly, no runtime impact).